# How to set User-Agent http-header for Auth0 Authorization for Proxy Communication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We are setting up a new Asp.Net Core 3.0 Web Application. When authenticating with Auth0 against this WebApp, the App tries to Reach .eu.auth0.com with HTTP GET. To Reach this site behind our corporate Proxy, the app needs to send an User-Agent http header.

My attempt was to add a custom Http-Message-Handler, which adds this header to all Requests of the Authorization Backend.

```
public class CustomHttpMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler {

    public CustomHttpMessageHandler() {
        InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "myApp/0.1.0");

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

This handler is set in the Startup.ConfigureServices():

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
       options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

}).AddJwtBearer(options => {
       options.SaveToken = true;
       options.Authority = domain;
       options.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:ApiIdentifier"];
       options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new CustomHttpMessageHandler();
});
```

When debugging, this Code is run and adds the User-Agent to the Request. The problem here is, that the app sends(before the GET) an HTTP OPTION Request to .eu.auth0.com which i am not able to modify.

Is there a way to set this Http-Header for authorization middlewares? Or even globally?
Or can i provide them with a whole custom Http-Client?